# hiding a box in webview android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am developing an application. I am using a webview to open a website. I have opened a url [Google Keep](http://keep.google.com) Now when the website opens it shows a box on the top which says **Get the App now from playstore something like this to take you to the PlayStore** How can I make the dialog hide permanently ? In my webview I have enabled javascript. I have also tried to find the javascript behind that box in url and wasn't able to find it.

```
private WebView wv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.keepWeb);
    WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("https://keep.google.com/");

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is simple code to open the url. That I am using. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show me that Dialog becoz i cant getting any dialog. i try the same

Comment: Previously I was testing on emulator it showed up there but Now on Device it is not..

Comment: Always try on Real physical device.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. :) I do have another problem. But I need to do some tests before I ask to someone.